# MariaDB ODBC Invalid string or buffer length

Tags: excel, vba, mariadb

I'm using Excel 2013 and VBA to connect to a MariaDB database the ODBC driver installed is version 2.0

I get an error when trying to execute an SQL statement:

```
    [ma-2.0.11][10.1.9-MariaDB]Invalid string or buffer length
```

I know the SQL isn't the cause of the problem as I have output the SQL into the immediate window and then executed it on the same system using HeidiSQL.

The operating system is Windows 7 64 bit.#

Connection string:

```
    Driver=MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver;Server=serverhostname;Port=3306;Database=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;
```

Comment: It looks like the connection string can you post what you are using?

Comment: Yes, its there now.

Comment: Haven't used MariaDB before, but most connection strings end with a `;`. Did you try adding that at the end?

Comment: Yes, just tried, same result.

Comment: Tack on `CHARSET=UTF8;`

Comment: Tried that already, problem fixed now by using version 1 of the ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I had another look on the MariaDB web-site at the ODBC driver and noticed that version 2.0 which is the one I was using was in Beta.

I uninstalled the beta and installed version 1.0, this has fixed the problem.